# 3D Rendering Libraries

Tags: 3d

I have a linux server periodically running some python and PHP scripts. Are there any linux-compaible libraries for rendering a simple 3D model with a simple texture programmatically? I would be able to convert the model into any format to be compatible.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do you just want to display an image of a model or do you want to create a 3D model that can be manipulated in the browser?

Comment: The former, but with a user-uploaded texture. I would know how to do the scripting to put the user textures into the system, I just need to be pointed towards some sort of system that does the rendering.